# How to assign large string to a variable without ILLEGAL Token error?

Tags: javascript, string, text

I need to assign a long string (4 pages worth of text) to a variable, so far I've been doing it like this

```
var myText = "[SOME] Text goes \
    .. here ? and 'there' \
    is more ( to \
    come etc. !)";
```

slashes at the end need to be added to all of the text, and I can't imagine how long this will take to do manually. Also, I get `ILLEGAL` error for some reason I don't understand for the first line.

Therefore I wanted to find out the best way to handle this situation. I was looking into solutions of passing in a .txt file, but would rather do it as a really long string (this is not a production app). Also string shown in example is random, showing that there can be a lot of various characters in it that need to be accounted for.

Comment: Can you show any more code? It's hard to identify what the issue is.

Comment: Nothing illegal in the text *as presented*.

Comment: @DrewGaynor I tried pasting it in first, but then all \ get screwed up. it is essentially the same, with longer lines of text and more of them. I guess issue no.1 is to figure out how to use very long string without manually adding these \ in it.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem.

Comment: and can use the "JS String" or "JSON.stringify" engines at http://danml.com/slim to turn large blocks of text into string literals. you can also wrap a command around the unescaped text, then a function, and use the function's .toString() method to grab the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate the string:

```
var t = ""
  +"text line 1"
  ...
  +"text line n"
```

But I would put the text in a text file and read it using xhr (on client) or io (on server).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a multiline string definition in javascript but you have several options :

- save your text in a file and read this file from your program
- use the `multiline` npm module which propose a hack to use function comments as multiline string definitions
- use ES6 multi-line template strings notation, which have multi-line support - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Multi-line_strings

saving the text in a file would seem to me as the preferred option in your case since the text seem to be very long an potentially coming from an untrusted source. You do not want the pasted text to close the string and start doing innapropriate function calls.

Comment: You _can_ have multiline strings in pure JavaScript.

Comment: @Andy: no you can't... you must use string literals, which need `'` or `"` to terminate, and those style of strings cannot contain a raw linebreak. without a linebreak, it's just one line. if you escape a trailing newline, then the newline is not part of the string, so that when used, the output still only has one line.

Comment: @Jerome what approach would you suggest for using a .file? I have tried jQuery.get to return data, but got cross domain error. The reason I wanted to use string is so I was able to do a .split() on it, I'm not sure how I could achieve this using a separate file.

Comment: I refer to string literals escaped on many lines a multi-line string. Clearly it also refers to something else too.